# Reemplazar vocales en una lista

Tags: python

Hola : Como hago para definir una función que tome una lista y cambie todas las vocales por +.
Hice una función pero solamente  me cambia la primer vocal de la lista.

```
def cambio_lista(lista): 
    for i in range(len(lista)):
        if lista[i] == "a":
            lista[i] = "_"
    return lista
```

Comment: ¿Podrías proporcionar material que llevas hecho para que con gusto podamos ayudarte con tus dudas específicas?

Comment: Hola silvana, debes agregar el código que has intentado aunque no funcione para tener un punto de partida y un error o problema concreto sobre el que responder. Tal como está la pregunta pude no ser muy bin recibida ... Por favor, [edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/281088/edit) tu pregunta  y agrega el código. Un saludo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
lista = ["a", "b", "c", "e", "f", "g", "i", "e", "w"]
def cambio_lista(lista): 
    for index, item in enumerate(lista):
        if item in "aeiou":
            lista[index] = "_"
    return lista
```

**Explicación:**
La función `enumerate` es muy util para conseguir a la vez el Index y el Valor de los elementos de una lista.

También fijate que utilizamos `in` en lugar de `==` para comprobar un elemento respecto a multiples opciones. (En este caso comparamos el valor actual con alguna de las 5 vocales). De lo contario tendrías que repetir mucho código.

**Eficiencia:**
Estos dos códigos hacen lo mismo:

```
if item in "aeiou":

if item == "a" or item == "e" or item == "i" or item == "o" or item == "u":
```

Está claro que la primera opción es menos liosa de entender.

**Comprobación:**

```
print(lista)
lista_cambiada = cambio_lista(lista)
print(lista_cambiada)
>>> ['a', 'b', 'c', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'i', 'e', 'w']
>>> ['_', 'b', 'c', '_', 'f', 'g', '_', '_', 'w']
```

Answer (score 3):

Se me ocurre una versión muy divertida y bonita usando `map`.

```
lista = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'z']
```

Y entonces usamos una función `lambda` como parámetro de la función `map`

```
lambda x: "+" if x in "aeiou" else x
```

Que, como dice, regresa el caracter '+' si x esta en "aeiou", de lo contrario regresa el valor de x.

Que ya dentro de la función map se vería así.

```
>>> nueva_lista = list(map(lambda x: "+" if x in "aeiou" else x, lista))
>>> print(nueva_lista)
['+', 'b', 'c', 'd', '+', '+', '+', 'z']
```

También puedes usar el módulo `re` de python.

Por ejemplo:

```
>>> nueva_lista = list(re.sub(r'[aeiou]', '+', ''.join(lista)))
>>> print(nueva_lista)
['+', 'b', 'c', 'd', '+', '+', '+', 'z']
```

Esto lo puedes volver una función.

```
reemplaza1 = lambda lista: list(re.sub(r'[aeiou]', '+', ''.join(lista)))
reemplaza2 = lambda lista: list(map(lambda x: '+' if x in 'aeiou' else x,lista))

print(reemplaza1(lista))
['+', 'b', 'c', 'd', '+', '+', '+', 'z']
print(reemplaza2(lista))
['+', 'b', 'c', 'd', '+', '+', '+', 'z']
```